# WaitForMultipleObjects для linux

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex, pthread

Как устроен мьютекс внутри( например `pthread_mutex_t`)? 
В частности интересует что происходит при вызове `pthread_mutex_lock`, при условии, что эта функция уже где-то была вызвана, будет ли ожидающий поток занимать процессор?

Вообще мне нужне кроссплатформенный аналог `WaitForMultipleObjects` под linux. Насколько я понимаю `pthread` такой возможности не предоставляет.

Является такая замена адекватной:

```
class Events
{
public:
    enum WaitResult
    {
        EVT_WAIT_ERROR   = -1,
        EVT_WAIT_TIMEOUT  = -2
    };

    WaitEvents(unsigned int capacity)
    {
        _capacity = capacity;
    }
    void set(const unsigned int index)
    {
        if(index >= 0 && index < _capacity)
        {
            _mtx.lock();
            _bits |= (1 << index);
            _mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
    void reset(const unsigned int index)
    {
        if(index >= 0 && index < _capacity)
        {
           _mtx.lock();
           _bits &= ~(1 << index);
           _mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
    int wait(unsigned int timeout)
    {
        Timer expiration(Timer::now() + timeout); 
        do
        {
             _mtx.lock();
             for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < _capacity; ++i)
             {
                 unsigned int mask = 1 << i;
                 if ((_bits & mask) == mask)
                 {
                     _mtx.unlock();
                     return i;
                 }
             }
             _mtx.unlock();
        }while( Timer::now() < expiration)
        return EVT_WAIT_TIMEOUT;
    }

private:
    WaitEvents(const WaitEvents&) = delete;
    const unsigned int _capacity;
    Mutex _mtx;
    unsigned int _bits;
};
```

В этом варианте мне не нравится постоянный опрос `Events::_bits`, не будет ли он загружать процессор?

Или лучший вариант изменить архитектуру приложения и не ждать сразу несколько событий?

Comment: С одним event`ом работать не проблема есть кроссплатформенная реализация  в библиотеке POCO(https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Event.html)  основанная на `pthread_cond_wait` для linux. Проблема именно в том что делать если нужно работать с множеством событий